# jMonkeyEngine ignores keyboard input in Nifty GUI form

Tags: java, user-interface, jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

Created a game login form using the Nifty GUI. The interface reacts to the movement and clicking of the mouse, but ignores the input in the text fields. Whether the program is looking for a click handler, instead of typing, or I don’t know what. What could be the case and how to fix it?

**Interface/screen.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nifty xmlns="http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/nifty-gui" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/void256/nifty-gui/1.4/nifty-core/src/main/resources/nifty.xsd 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/void256/nifty-gui/1.4/nifty-core/src/main/resources/nifty.xsd">
    <useStyles filename="nifty-default-styles.xml"/>
    <useControls filename="nifty-default-controls.xml"/>
    <screen id="start" controller="mygame.LoginScreen">
        <layer id="background" childLayout="center">
            <image filename="Interface/start-background.jpg"></image>
        </layer>
        <layer id="foreground" childLayout="center">
            <panel id="panel" height="25%" width="75%" align="center" childLayout="horizontal">
                <panel id="panel_left" height="100%" width="25%" align="left" childLayout="vertical">
                    <text text="E-mail:" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
                    <text text="Password:" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
                </panel>
                <panel id="panel_center" height="100%" width="50%" align="center" childLayout="vertical">
                    <control name="textfield" maxLength="50" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
                    <control name="textfield" maxLength="100" passwordChar="*" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
                </panel>
                <panel id="panel_right" height="100%" width="25%" align="right" childLayout="vertical">

                </panel>
            </panel>
        </layer>
    </screen>
    <screen id="hud" controller="de.lessvoid.nifty.screen.DefaultScreenController">

    </screen>
</nifty>
```

**src/mygame/Main.java:**

```
package mygame;

import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.renderer.RenderManager;
import com.jme3.niftygui.NiftyJmeDisplay;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty;

public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }
    public String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public Nifty nifty = null;
    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        NiftyJmeDisplay niftyDisplay = NiftyJmeDisplay.newNiftyJmeDisplay(assetManager, inputManager, audioRenderer, guiViewPort);
        nifty = niftyDisplay.getNifty();
        nifty.fromXml("Interface/screen.xml", "start");
        guiViewPort.addProcessor(niftyDisplay);
        inputManager.beginInput();
        flyCam.setDragToRotate(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        //TODO: add update code
        nifty.update();
        inputManager.update(tpf);
    }
}
```

**src/mygame/LoginScreen.java:**

```
package mygame;

import com.jme3.app.Application;
import com.jme3.app.state.BaseAppState;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.screen.Screen;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.screen.ScreenController;

public class LoginScreen extends BaseAppState implements ScreenController {

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Application app) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Application app) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onEnable() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDisable() {

    }
    @Override
    public void update(float tpf) {

    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Nifty nifty, Screen screen) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartScreen() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndScreen() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in XML. Interactive interface elements without an id remain static. Need not so:

```
<control name="textfield" maxLength="50" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
<control name="textfield" maxLength="100" passwordChar="*" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
```

Well right:

```
<control id="mail" name="textfield" maxLength="50" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
<control id="password" name="textfield" maxLength="100" passwordChar="*" font="Interface/Fonts/Default.fnt"/>
```

Then the fields are activated.